# Can I serialize a property using a Jackson @JsonView?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-view

I have a complicated class in my REST API:

```
class Complicated {
    String foo
    Integer bar
    Instant baz
    ...
    // lots more
}
```

I also have another class that contains a collection of `Complicated`:

```
class HasComplications {
    String description

    List<Complicated> complications
}
```

When I serialize my `HasComplications` (with Spring MVC), I only want a snippet of each `Complicated`:

```
{
    description: "hello world",
    complications: [ {
      foo: "foo1",
      bar: 42
    ] }
}
```

When I'm directly serializing a `Complicated`, I can use `@JsonView` to tell Jackson which set of properties to serialize:

```
class Complicated {
    @JsonView(Views.Snippet) String foo
    @JsonView(Views.Snippet) Integer bar
    Instant baz
    ...
    // lots more
}
```

However, when I serialize `Complicated` transitively in the `complications` property, Jackson serializes all of the properties. Is there a way for me to declaratively tell it "use this view when serializing this property"?

```
class HasComplications {
    String description

    @UseJsonView(Views.Snippet)
    List<Complicated> complications
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality currently.

One thing you can do is to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on property.
However, I think that would only work for POJO values and not to contents of `List`s or `Map`s so that does not help you here.
Filing an issue to make this work for structured types might make sense.

Comment: It looks like there was a similar feature request a while back, and I've commented on it.